# Turn 3x3 data.frame into 1x9 data.frame while preserving row and column names

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am having trouble coming up with an elegant solution to this seemingly simple data manipulation problem.  I can see a looped solution but I assume there is a 1-2 function single-line solution.

Here is what I have:

```
x <- data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3),
                c2=c(4,5,6),
                c3=c(7,8,9),
                row.names = c("r1","r2","r3"))

> x
   c1 c2 c3
r1  1  4  7
r2  2  5  8
r3  3  6  9
```

And here is what I want:

```
> y
     c1.r1 c1.r2 c1.r3 c2.r1 c2.r2 c2.r3 c3.r1 c3.r2 c3.r3
1    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

How do I manipulate `x` to give me `y`?

Comment: `dat <- as.data.frame.list(unlist(x)); colnames(dat) <- c(t(outer(colnames(x), rownames(x), FUN=paste, sep=".")))`

Comment: You should check out the `plyr` package, too. I think `gather` is a great function for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
R> unlist(lapply(x, setNames, rownames(x)))
c1.r1 c1.r2 c1.r3 c2.r1 c2.r2 c2.r3 c3.r1 c3.r2 c3.r3 
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

A `data.frame` is a list, so `lapply` just loops over the columns. Then it sets the names of each vector to the `rownames` of the data.frame. Then `unlist` flattens the list to a vector (recursively, setting names, by default).

Comment: I ultimately used the solution @akrun gives in the comments above because it works with non-square data frames.

Comment: @AdamC: can you elaborate? What about my solution doesn't "work" with a non-square data.frame? The output looks fine to me if I add a `c4` column.

Comment: I encountered this error with my actual data and misinterpreted it:  
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :   'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]`  It turns out I was trying to apply your code to a matrix and after I converted it to a data frame **it worked as expected**.  Thanks!